# time not converting into proper int to store in db

Tags: android, time

I am concatenating two edittext boxes.  One has date and the other has time.  I then change them into a time and store them into the db.  I ran the debugger and the date object seems to be correct until I convert it into an int, then it is not converting correctly.  Here is my code

```
  Time userTime;
    userTime= new Time(date.getText().toString().concat(time.getText().toString()));

    int enteredTime = (int) ((userTime).toMillis(true) / 1000);
```

UpDate: For some reason all the info is going under the timezone for userTime?? Any have any ideas why

Answer (score 0):

```
int enteredTime = (int) ((userTime).toMillis(true) / 1000);
```

It is always better to store time in long than int. I guess it could be the reason why you are seeing wrong time.

Try something like this below:

```
 long enteredTime = (long) ((userTime).toMillis(true) / 1000);
```

Comment: No, I am still getting the same error. The year 1969 keep showing up

Comment: Are you sure date.getText().toString().concat(time.getText().toString()) is correct value? I would print this value first before passing it to Time

Comment: All the info is going into time zone for userTime

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using the converted time? Most java code likes milliseconds rather than seconds, so try omitting the division by 1000. Be sure you use a `long` rather than an `int` in this case.